slurm installed using os repo. but the pmix not enabled in " srun --mpi=list"
I'm installing slurm from the Ubuntu OS repo, which is available in Ubuntu 22.04. I'm able to install slurm successfully, but the pmix is not showing.
root@node1:~# srun --mpi=list
srun: MPI types are...
srun: none
srun: cray_shasta
srun: pmi2

This is working with RHEL8. Are there any steps I need to fix to enable slurm with pmix?
Note: slurm needs to install using the OS repository, not from any sources binaries.
OS details:
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy

slurm version in Ubuntu 22.04 is with: slurm-wlm 21.08.5

Does this guide provide any help?
